# Why does music start playing when I log in?

Tags: login

When I login I suddenly start to hear music. I haven't configured anything to do this. As I start to do things the music stops. What causes this?

Comment: have you checked your startup list ?

Comment: I hadn't changed any part of my startup. It really did turn out to be the cursor over a music file in the very middle of my Desktop, as below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you login your cursor is positioned at the center of your desktop.

If there happens to be an sound file there your system can helpfully preview (play) it.

It may sound trivial or silly but when it happened it astonished me until I realized the reason. It also surprised one other person I've corresponded with.

Comment: I think this is no longer the default behaviour, and I miss it. I now use `gnome-sushi` but it's not quite the same as it requires a tap of the space bar. Oh, well. It is now safe to keep audio files in the center of the desktop again, if that's what you want.